# How to list contents of a .app file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to list files in .ipa file.I am trying to extract ipa for testing how much secure my database inside ipa. After extracting it i have got Myappname.app file. i want to list contents of this file in python.i have tried following code it not listing contents

```
 import os
 for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
     if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(file)
```

but i am able to contents of Myappname.app file using following Java code.

```
    void listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
     File directory = new File(directoryName);

     // get all the files from a directory
      File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
      for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            files.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why are you checking for `file.endswith(".txt")` in python code but not in Java code?

Comment: i am trying to list all .db files in a directory. by mistake i added here as .txt

Answer (score 0):

Your `file` is only filename so you have to open it and read content

```
print( open("/mydir/" + file, 'r').read() )
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using  glob.glob & os.path.isfile. extracted folder contains some files and folder. listdir throws error if i pass files instead folder so i filtered files using os.path.isfile && os.path.isdir returns false to this folder.

```
    if os.path.exists(ipaExtractedPath):
        for file in os.listdir(ipaExtractedPath):
            if not os.path.isfile(ipaExtractedPath+"/"+file):
                for f in glob.glob(ipaExtractedPath +"/"+file+"/*.db"):
                    try:
                        // some code here
                            break
                        conn.close()
                    except sqlite3.Error:
                        print "Error open db.\n"
```